# Запятая или точка с ней?

Tags: пунктуация

Правда, что оба варианта правильны и что 2-й – лучше, чем 1-й?

`1. Арбуз, мною съеденный, был-таки, во-первых, не безвкусный, а во-вторых, поле-, по мимо этого, -зный, при этом он недорого-таки, когда я его приобрёл, стоил.`

`2. Арбуз, мною съеденный, был-таки, во-первых, не безвкусный, а во-вторых, поле-, по мимо этого, -зный; при этом он недорого-таки, когда я его приобрёл, стоил.`

Comment: Ладно ещё разбить слово "самогон", состоящее из двух основ, но это-то одноосновное. Никто так не станет говорить! Вы корень разделили, звучит ужасно!

Comment: По-Леопольдовому, думаю, правильно сказать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я тоже считаю, что второй лучше.

*Арбуз, мною съеденный, был-таки, во-первых, не безвкусный, а во-вторых, поле-, по мимо этого, -зный; **при этом** он недорого-таки, когда я его приобрёл, стоил* — здесь подчëркивается самостоятельность двух частей.

*Арбуз, мною съеденный, был-таки, во-первых, не безвкусный, а во-вторых, поле-, по мимо этого, -зный, **при этом** он недорого-таки, когда я его приобрёл, стоил* — а здесь присоединительный союз ПРИ ЭТОМ присоединяет вторую часть предложения-присоединения, отбиваясь запятой.

Второй вариант лучше, потому что первое предложение сильно распространено и без этого имеет много запятых — поэтому лучше разбить на две части, чтобы лучше читалось да и выглядело.